# how to stop Handler working in android?

Tags: android, handler, intentservice

My APP has to start some time consuming job when receiving ACTION_SCREEN_OFF, and interrupt the job when receiving ACTION_SCREEN_ON if job is still going on.

```
public class TimeConsumingWorkIntentService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       TimeConsumingWork();
    }
}

public class ScreenStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, TimeConsumingWorkIntentService.class);
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
          mContext.startService(intent );
      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
          mContext.stopService(intent );
      }
  }
}
```

By print log of time, I find time consuming work is still going on stop the  TimeConsumingWorkIntentService (when receiving ACTION_SCREEN_ON).

why ?

Answer (score 3):

Use

`// Cancel the runnable`

`myHandler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable);`

Ok , then you can do something like this

```
Runnable r = new Runnable{
public void run(){
    if(booleanCancelMember != false){
        // within this you make the call to handler and work
        // Since you block the call the handler wont get repeated
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Arju. I tried your method before, it does NOT work for some unknown reason(sorry I don't remember why).  And I try with IntentService, it does NOT work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this like that. When you start your `IntentService`, it will call `onHandleIntent()` on a separate worker thread. That mehod then calls `TimeConsumingWork()`. Stopping the service will not interrupt the execution of the worker thread. It just tells the worker thread that when it has finished processing the current `Intent`, it should stop.

What you will need to do is to have your `TimeConsumingWork()` method periodically look to see if it should stop. You can do this by setting a `static boolean` variable and have `TimeConsumingWork()` periodically check this variable and quit if it is set.

You don't need to call `stopService()` on an `IntentService` as it will stop itself when it has nothing to do.